# Questions on a formula for the Mertens function

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture, riemann-hypothesis, mobius-function

The [Mertens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function) $M(x)$ is defined as follows.

**(1)** $\quad M(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\mu(n)$

I've noticed the Merten's function can also be evaluated as follows which is related to [OEIS entry A087003](https://oeis.org/A087003) and the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

**(2)** $\quad M(x)=\sum\limits_{n=\left\lfloor\frac{x-2}{4}\right\rfloor+1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{x-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\mu(2\,n+1)$

I've verified formula (2) above for the first $10,000$ positive integer values of $x$.

**Question (1)**: Has formula (2) above been proven (or disproven) and if not, can it be?

I've read the following conjecture on the growth of $M(x)$ for any $\epsilon<1/2$ is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis (see [Weisstein, Eric W. "Mertens Conjecture." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensConjecture.html)).

**(3)** $\quad M(x)=O\left(x^{1/2+\epsilon}\right)$

**Question (2)**: Assuming formula (2) above is correct, does it show any promise with respect to improving upon the fastest known algorithm for computing $M(x)$ and/or the tightest known error bound on the growth of $M(x)$?

Comment: Yes you are right, my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing special happening here. Let $$F(s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mu(2n+1)(2n+1)^{-s}, \qquad \frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = (1-2^{-s}) F(s)$$
$$f(x) = \sum_{2n+1 \le x} \mu(2n+1), \qquad M(x) = f(x)-f(x/2)$$

Comment: can do it directly by separating the $\mu(2(2k+1))=-\mu(2k+1)$ since $\mu$ is multiplicative, $\mu(4k)=0$ and cancelling out the odd $\mu$ for the first half, but using RZ is cooler!